# Find missing symbols in mingw library

Tags: mingw-w64

Given ar libraries and possibly object files, what is the best way to find all of the unresolved external symbols? One possibility is to run the linker and then capture the errors, but sometimes it stops after a certain number of symbols. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `mingw-w64` installation's `bin` directory, along with
the C and C++ compilers, linker and make tool, you should other 
programs that make up the [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

Several of these (`nm`, `objdump`, `readelf`) can parse the symbol tables of object files or shared or
static libraries. The simplest to use is probably [`nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm). Assuming
that the `bin` directory is in your `PATH`, open a command prompt
in the directory containing the libraries or object files your are
interested in and run:

```
nm -u libfoo.a
```

or:

```
nm -u foo.obj
```

to list the undefined symbols in `libfoo.a` or in `foo.obj`.

If these files contain C++ symbols that you want to see demangled then
add `-C` to the `nm` options.

These tools all recognize that a static library `libfoo.a` is just
an archive of object files so `nm ... libfoo.a` gives you just the
same results as if `libfoo.a` was replaced with a list of the object
files within it.